# Set checkedlistbox value to checked does not work properly

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

I tired this both codes to set a Item checked in a checkedlistbox:

```
CheckedListBox2.SetItemCheckState(0, CheckState.Checked)
```

and

```
 CheckedListBox2.SetItemChecked(0, True)
```

both work, and set the item as checked as expected.. but if i call this code, I get a message box..

```
If (CheckedListBox2.SelectedItems.Count > 0) Then
   do some code...
else 
   msgbox("not good...")
end if
```

If i manually REMOVE the check from the checkbox and set it back then the above code does not show the msgbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be looking at the checked items not the selected items:

```
CheckedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

SelectedItems are different than checked items.  You should change your code to reference the [CheckedItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
If (CheckedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count > 0) Then
   'do some code...
Else 
   MsgBox("not good...")
End If
```